# Bit Rate issues on ubuntu 12.04 Centrino Advanced-N 6205 wireless card

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm having some issues with my wireless connection.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
```

Kernel Version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dtabar-laptop 3.13.0-49-generic #81~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 25 16:32:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The issue is with the bit rate, it's stuck between 1Mb/s and 6 Mb/s as you can see:

```
$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"NewSocrates"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: E8:DE:27:42:35:82   
      Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:116   Missed beacon:0
```

sudo lshw -class network output:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 34
   serial: 84:3a:4b:33:bf:5c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-49-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=y es wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn  resources: irq:47 memory:f1c00000-f1c01fff
```

Anything I'm missing? Any ideas of what may be causing this?

Thanks!

Diego

Comment: Here is what you've missed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Here is the information requested: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10787102/

Comment: Your WiFi is on channel 11 as are 6 other WiFis.  Can you change the router to use channel 2 and report back?

Comment: Thanks @Fabby seems to be working better after switching channels. http://paste.ubuntu.com/10853919/

Comment: Let me convert that to an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10787102/) of the [wireless debugging script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) that your WiFi is sharing channel 11 with 6 other WiFi networks close to you.

Please go to your router and change the channel to 2 (currently unused by any of the WiFi networks around you).  That will improve your throughput.